# .load causing total page refresh in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

So I've got a simple site with a menu bar and a content area. When I click one of the buttons in the menu bar, it's supposed to do a quick fadeIn transition on a graphical element of the content area, and load external content into a div.

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
$(".contentdivs").fadeIn(1000);
$(".content").load("external.html");
});
```

This works exactly as intended in Chrome, Safari and Firefox, but not in Internet Explorer.

In Explorer, clicking #button1 will trigger the .Fadein and the .load (I can see the transition and the external data render very briefly) but then the entire page refreshes, and the external content gets unloaded.

Any ideas why this is happening, and how to fix it?

Comment: Something *else* is causing the page to reload. Probably a script in "external.html" which is being executed. See http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Most probably something is failing in your code, causing the click handler to fail, causing IE to do the default behaviour for a button - which is to submit its containing form, causing a reload. Check for JS errors.

Comment: Consider making a small repro of the issue. This will enable us to better assist you with debugging the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the button an anchor tag? You probably need to prevent the click event's default action and stop the event from bubbling in case there's an anchor parent to the button:

```
$("#button1").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".contentdivs").fadeIn(1000);
    $(".content").load("external.html");
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! 

For future reference and my own edification, is this a case of Internet Explorer being too finicky, or a case of other browsers being to permissive?